# Sum hours on php

Tags: php

I am trying to sum hours with the format of MySQL 00:00:00, I sum them with a foreach, but when the sum gets to 24:00:00 it starts in 00:00:00, and I want the sum to follow to 24:10:00, 25:00:00, etc.

This is my code to sum them:

```
foreach($hours as $h){
 $sumaHoras = date('H:i:s', strtotime($sumaHoras) + strtotime($h->horas) - strtotime('00:00'));
}
```

Comment: You have to sum up hours separatly from minutes and seconds as integers and then convert everything to hours.

Comment: Thanks Valadislav

Comment: If it's helpful and sounds like an answer I will post it as answer. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with only returning the hour parts of date(), you are removing anything bigger than
a full day, so it will only ever return something between 00:00 and 23:59. You should use something other than
date() and only when all the seconds are added up.

So instead you should try something like this:

```
function sec2hours($seconds){
  $units = array(
    'hours'   => 3600,
    'minutes' => 60,
    'seconds' => 1,
  );
  foreach($units as &$unit){
    $quot  = intval($seconds / $unit);
    $seconds -= $quot * $unit;
    $unit  = $quot;
  }
  $str = array();
  foreach($units as $name => $value){
    $str[] = ($value === 0?'00':$value);
  }
  return implode(':',$str);
}

$sum = 0;
foreach($hours as $h){
 $sum += strtotime($h->horas) - strtotime('00:00');
}
$sumaHoras = sec2hours($sum);
```

The second problem is that strtotime() returns false on hours that should have rolled over into days like 25:00,
so if you get one input like that, it will become 0 - strtotime('00:00') and you end up with a huge negative sum.
But if all the inputs are between 00-23:00-59 it should be alright.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code helpful

```
        foreach ($timeArr $key=> $timevalue) {

            $timesumArr[$key]=date('H:i:s', array_sum(array_map('strtotime', $timevalue)));

        }
```